# Howto get the number of available updates/security-updates in ubuntu server

Tags: server, apt, updates, c++, byobu

I'm writing a small daemon in c/c++ and I need to get the number of updates available and how many of them are security updates.
So far I know I could use either update-notifier or nagios but just for getting the number of updates these have way to many dependencies that i don't need/want on an headless server.
Is there any way to get this information directly through apt or are there even libs for c/c++ with this functionality?
I have byobu running on my server and it somehow retrieves this information and displays it but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check` from the `update-notifier-common` package. Run `/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check -h` for usage information. It has both human readable and machine readable forms.

Comment: This is how your motd does it. So I believe the package is already installed by default.

Comment: OK i just checked and if i install update-notifier-common instead of update-notifier i don't get prompted to install the 160~ dependencies so this works thanks. But if anyone knows of a good c/c++ lib an quick hint would still be appreciated. For now I'll go with this solution.

Comment: The update-motd.d skript and apt-check both are not installed on my server but they are present on my pc so maybe it is a server os thing.